# How do I block outbound traffic except a few IPs via IPTables?

Tags: networking, router, iptables

I have an Asus wireless router that was flashed with MERLIN.  I also own several IP Cameras connected via Wifi.  I want to prevent the IP Cameras from trying to call home by disabling outbound. Which I did with this

However there are a few things that I would like to do.

1. **BY DEFAULT** Prevent IP cameras to send any data outside my network.
2. Exception: IP Cameras need connect and send to port 465 (SMTPS port) to send an email.
3. Exception: I want a handful of IP addresses (some are IP ranges) to be able to remotely access the camera via PORT. So I need a rule is an exception to the default.

I have port forwarding setup already.

So for example: 192.168.1.2:123  (123 is the port I use to access the camera via browser) is the way I can connnect to it online via browser.  I also want it accessible not ONLY locally but outside the home network but with a handful of IPs. If you aren't the IP address then you get DROPPED if you are you are accepted. Like a bouncer.  So essentially my work computer can access that camera via port 123 is what I am trying to do.

I understand linux and I know some of the flags for IPTABLES but just not enough so i need an expert.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The job will be easier if your cameras are on a standard subnet. Then you can mention subnet in each rule mentioned below. Otherwise, you better see [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/474073/how-to-load-a-list-of-addresses-into-iptables-dynamically) or similar.

After dealing with how to specify IP range of cams, you can easily drop all packets initiated by your cameras (supposing they are tcp connections) using --syn option. This is an example assuming all cameras ( <=8 cams and no other systems) are on a subnet of 192.168.1.0/29

```
#1    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/29 -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
#2    iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.0/29 -p tcp --sport 465 -j ACCEPT
#3    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/29 -p tcp --syn -j DROP
#4    iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/29 -p udp -j DROP
```

Add #2 only if NAT is not done on the Linux box.

To publish cams:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1202 -j DNAT 192.168.1.2:123
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1203 -j DNAT 192.168.1.3:123
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1204 -j DNAT 192.168.1.4:123
```

but let only those specific IP addresses access them:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s trustedip1 -d 192.168.1.0/29 -p tcp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s trustedip2 -d 192.168.1.0/29 -p tcp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s trustedip3 -d 192.168.1.0/29 -p tcp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.0/29 -p tcp --dport 123 -j DROP
```

Of course if Camera addresses are not neatly in one subnet, you have to swap  192.168.1.0/29 pwith camera ip address and repeat the rule for each.

Comment: @m-tajbakhsh thank you so much! I understood how you are doing this now. I do have a few questions:  the part where you say to publish the cameras they look like it’s port forwarding but to a local port. Is that the same thing?  Also does the rules appear before the default tcp and udp drop (#3 &#4)? I assume so because it’s done in order

Comment: by publishing i simply meant port forwarding. yes, order is important.

Comment: I am having more troubles.  So I tried what you suggested and placed the rules on the 'firewall-start' file and I used the INSERT to make sure the drop was added first then the other rules to follow.  (i tried append, didn't work).  It's straightforward but I have no idea why I can't get it to work as it should. The issue is just that it won't get the desired results. It would close it all (ports/connection).  Thoughts?

Comment: you should try insert very carefully. get a listing and make sure drop is at the end of this set of rules. the rest, it believe you should put configs in your post. there must be details we've missed to consider.